# How to reinitialize ChatService to prevent recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) Quickblox

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

**recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)**

I get this error on weak devices when wake up the phone after some sleep. Coming in sleep mode I logout ChatService in onStop method of Activity. And in OnStart make the full login to Session and chat user. But it doesn't help. After 20-30 sec established connection is breaking and starts automatically reconnect. It doesn't look good from potential user. Could you please help me how to reinitialize ChatService to restore the first state as in time when the app was loaded.

I tryed to destroy ChatService after logout
QBChatSevice.getInstance().destroy();

But i doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to organize connection work in the service which is running when the app is in the background mode.
As an example, please have a look at how this method is realized in Q-municate app:
https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/tree/master